# Error in SQL query error #1064 in primary key declaration

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE conversationlog(
    bot TINYINT( 3 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
    id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    input TEXT,
    response TEXT,
    uid VARCHAR( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
    enteredtime TIMESTAMP( 14 ) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id ) ,
    KEY botid( bot )
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

MySQL said:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(14) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY  (id),   KEY botid (bot) )
>   ENGINE=MyISAM' at l ine 7

written this SQL query to create a conversation log, I don't know why is the error coming. Please rectify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pass value parameter in `TIMESTAMP`. Instead of:

```
enteredtime TIMESTAMP( 14 ) NOT NULL ,
```

use this:

```
enteredtime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
```

Answer (score 3):

You missed a space between `enteredtime` and `TIMESTAMP`:

```
enteredtime TIMESTAMP( 14 ) NOT NULL ,
```

Comment: that was while pasting here,there is no space between entered time and timestamp still the same error

Comment: As stated below, try removing the (14) from timestamp. Get it to be `TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 1):

There is a space missing ... it should be like

```
enteredtime TIMESTAMP( 14 ) NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change this:

```
enteredtime TIMESTAMP( 14 ) NOT NULL ,
```

To this:

```
enteredtime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
```

It will work

Example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9342f)

Comment: If you are fine with the answers presented. Then remember to accept it